# Kibana4 search bar

Tags: iframe, elasticsearch, kibana

I just started using Kibana4 and they have this new feature of embedding the dashboard into your app using an iframe generated in Kibana. Pretty cool and easy to use. However, the search bar is NOT embedded as well with the dashboard and it's *very very* necessary that I have the search bar in the kibana dashboard. Does anyone have any idea how I can include it with the iframe? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a future enhancement I see.

https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/3046